# Error when converting Java Constructors from Abstract classes and super keyword to C#?

Tags: java, c#, constructor

I have two classes in Java that I'm trying to convert to C#. One is an abstract class named RemoteButton, the other is derived from it called TVRemoteMute. I was able to convert most of the members in the abstract RemoteButton class. One member is abstract buttonNinePressed(), implemented in TVRemoteMute, the other is a virtual member buttonFivePressed() implemented in the base class. My issue is with the constructor of the TVRemoteMute class. It highlights on two words, the constructor name, and the word super inside the method. The constructor name error reads, "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal paramater 'newDevice' of 'RemoteButton.RemoteButton(EntertainmentDevice)'. The "super" keyword error reads that the name does not exist in the current context. How would I implement this constructor from Java to C#, so my class can process the constructor?

```
public abstract class RemoteButton
{
    private EntertainmentDevice theDevice;

    public RemoteButton(EntertainmentDevice newDevice)
    {
        theDevice = newDevice;
    }

    public virtual void buttonFivePressed()
    {
        theDevice.buttonFivePressed();
    }

    public abstract void buttonNinePressed();

 }

public class TVRemoteMute : RemoteButton
{
    public TVRemoteMute(EntertainmentDevice newDevice)
    {
        super(newDevice);
    }

    public override void buttonNinePressed()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("TV was Muted");

    }
}
```

Comment: And what's so `super` in your `base` class? :D `public TVRemoteMute(EntertainmentDevice newDevice) : base(newDevice)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The keyword `super` is not used in C#; calling a base class' constructor is different than in Java.

Change your constructor in `TVRemoteMute` to this:

```
public TVRemoteMute(EntertainmentDevice newDevice) : base(newDevice)
{

}
```

Actually, I prefer this if you aren't doing anything else in the constructor's body, but it really doesn't matter:

```
public TVRemoteMute(EntertainmentDevice newDevice) : base(newDevice) { }
```

The other error should fix itself once you compile it.